# Modifier key to open bookmark in a new private window

Tags: firefox, shortcuts

In Firefox if you hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key when you click a bookmark the page opens in a new tab. If you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you click a bookmark the page opens in a new window. Is there a modifier key to open bookmarks in a new private window?

Comment: No such answers in - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct#search

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such exact option.

You could perhaps use the extension
[PrivateBookmark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/privatebookmark/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search),
described as :

> Looks for bookmarks containing keyword (defined in preferences) in the title field. For all found URLs a listener is defined that cancels request in normal window and instead opens a new private tab for the url.

This is an awkward way to mark bookmarks as private by their title.

Firefox itself allows to right-click a bookmark and open in a new
Private window.

I don't know of any other option.

[image]